# Creating one line string with Dictionary Keys in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to create one line string with dictionary's keys in Python3.
I can print them in one line with end='' function but i can't update like that.

**I have a dictionary like below.**

```
array = {
'MERCHANT': "TEST",
'ORDER_REF':  "Test123",
'BACK_REF': "http://2ac99X37.ngrok.io/",
'ORDER_PNAME[0]': "BLA",
'ORDER_PCODE[0]': "BLA",
'ORDER_PINFO[0]': "BLA",
'ORDER_PRICE[0]': "1",
'ORDER_VAT[0]': "18",
```

}

**And i'm sorting them to their keys and getting length**

```
for k, v in sorted(array.items()):
hashstring =str(len(v)) + str(v)
```

**But when i print the hashstring at this step, they printing like below**

```
25http://2ac99X37.ngrok.io/
4TEST
3BLA
3BLA
3BLA
11
7Test123
218
```

**I need to update them like below because true hash calculation**

```
25http://2ac99X37.ngrok.io/ 4TEST 3BLA 3BLA 3BLA 11 7Test123 218
```

> Like i was mentioned above; I can print them in one line with end=''
>   function but this is not effecting the "hashstring" parameters value.

My hash calculation code is like below.

```
signature = hmac.new(secret.encode('utf-8'), hashstring.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.md5).hexdigest()
```

Could you please assist me ?

Best,

Comment: initialize `hashstring` before loop and then use `hashstring +=` instead of `hashstring =`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't properly formatted.

I think the issue is in your for loop.

If you write `hashstring =str(len(v)) + str(v)` it will represent a different value every time you print it.

Try

```
hashstring=''
for k, v in sorted(array.items()):
    hashstring += str(len(v)) + str(v)
print(hashstring)
```

Comment: OMG! I can cry right now, i can't believe it's due to indent.
Thank you very much !, its work @bphi

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `hashstring` before your loop, then keep concatenating to it in your loop, as the following:

```
hashstring = ''
for k, v in sorted(array.items()):
    hashstring += '{}{} '.format(len(v), v)
hashstring = hashstring[:-1]  # to remove the trailing space
```

Output:

```
25http://2ac99X37.ngrok.io/ 4TEST 3BLA 3BLA 3BLA 11 7Test123 218
```

or you can use list comprehension instead of the loop to do it in one line as the following:

```
hashstring = ' '.join(['{}{}'.format(len(v), v) for k, v in sorted(array.items())])
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to want to combine many individual strings into one string with a separator, you want to use `.join`. So, accumulate your parts into a list, then `.join` them:

```
In [6]: hashparts = []

In [7]: for k, v in sorted(array.items()):
   ...:     hashparts.append(str(len(v)) + str(v))
   ...:

In [8]: hashstring = ' '.join(hashparts)

In [9]: print(hashstring)
25http://2ac99X37.ngrok.io/ 4TEST 3BLA 3BLA 3BLA 11 7Test123 218
```

Comment: Hi @juanpa.arrivillaga,
It's works too ! Thank you very much, but i will prefer to use bphi's way to update them in a one line.

Comment: @Gokturk just so you know, that method can be O(n^2) instead of the above O(n) solution, however, if the strings are small it won't be a big deal.

Comment: Hi @MosesKoledoye
I'm preparing a sample code and i want to do this from the simplest way

Comment: @MosesKoledoye to make the logic explicit. Anyone is free to convert to the equivalent list comprehension.